# True false question- regarding Polynomial function

Tags: real-analysis

Let A be the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{ R}$ that satisfy the following

two properties:

• $f$ has derivatives of all orders, and

• for all $x, y \in \mathbb{ R},$

$f(x + y) − f(y − x)=2xf'(y)$.

Which of the following sentences is true?

$(a)$ Any $f \in A$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $1.$

$(b)$ Any $f \in A$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $2.$

$(c)$ There exists $f \in A$ which is not a polynomial.

$(d)$ There exists $f \in A$ which is a polynomial of degree $4.$

My attempt :$\frac{f(x + y) − f(y − x)}{x+y -(y-x)}=f'(y)$

option $a) $ is  wrong  because   if degree  is less then  $1$,  i mean $f(x) = \sqrt x$  then it will not be  a polynomial so  it will be false

option $c) $  will  also False  $f$  will be polynomial  because $f(x)$ is continious

option $b)$ and  option $d)$  are  satisfied  the given  property    so  it will be  obviously True ..

correct answer will be option $a)$  and option $d)$

Is  it correct ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: When you say that Option (1) is wrong, do you mean Option (a)?

Comment: @Josh ya  i have  edit its

Comment: Your analysis has many errors.   (a) Polynomial degree less than 1 is constant. $\sqrt{x}$ is not a polynomial.  (b)  Some  polynomial of degree 2 will not satisfy,  (c) There are continuous functions (example $sin(x)$) which are not polynomials. (d) Prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you say option (a) is false is incorrect. Polynomials with degree less than or equal to $1$ are in the are either in the form $cx$ or $c$. The degree of $\sqrt{x}$ is not defined since $\sqrt{x}$ is not a polynomial - polynomials, by definition only take integer powers.

The reason you say that (c) is false is also incorrect. While true that $f$ is continuous, there exist continuous functions that are not polynomials.

Let's take the expression that you found and see what we can determine from it. You found that for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ \begin{align*} 
\frac{f(y+x)-f(y-x)}{(y+x)-(y-x)} &= f'(y)
\end{align*}
Imagine what this looks like graphically. $f'(y)$ is a linear approximation for $f$ at $y$. That is, $f'(y)$ is the slope of the line that lies tangent to $f(y)$. But for any $x$, we also have that the line connecting $f(y+x)$ and $f(y-x)$ has slope $f'(y)$. Since this is true for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that the secant line around $y$ is equal to the tangent line. This can only happen if $f$  is a line. This is equivalent to choice (a).

For some extrapolation, imagine the function $f(x) = x^2$. We have that $f'(0) = 0$. Additionally, \begin{align*}
\frac{f(0+x)-f(0-x)}{(0+x)-(0-x)} &= \frac{x^2-x^2}{2x}\\
&= 0\\
&= f'(0)
\end{align*}
Try drawing a picture of this. Draw the tangent line of $f(x) = x^2$ at $0$. You get a straight line of slope $0$. Now choose any $x$ and connect $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ with a straight line - this is called the secant line. This line should have a slope of $0$. This is the property that $f$ has: that given any $y$, if we take $f(y+x)$ and $f(y-x)$ for any $x$, the line connecting these two points should have the slope $f'(y)$. We see that $f(x) = x^2$ has this property at $0$. But if you try doing this at any other point for $f(x)= x^2$, it doesn't work. Try playing with a few functions and try proving that this property holds at all points if and only if $f$ has constant slope - that is, that $f$ is a line.

Comment: GIve me  5 minutes  to  read /thinks  ur solution

Comment: @ Jose im not getting   how  secant  line  around  y  is  equal to the tangent line  ?

Comment: @jasmine Let me add a little bit to my answer, give me a minute